# Cannot write dictionary in txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to make a python script for storing the birthday dates and storing it in a text file without repeating the same name and date of birth but I am not able to do it. And I am using python 3.6. I was able to write but unable to retrieve it.  I want a hand to solve this problem.

```py
Birthday = {}

with open('Birthday.txt', 'r') as file:  # opening txt file in read mode since it doesn't support in append mode

file.seek(0)
content = file.readlines()

while True:
    name = input('Enter name:')  # asking for name
    if name in Birthday:
        birth_day = Birthday[name] + 'is a birthday of' + name + '.' + '\n'
        print(birth_day)

        with open('Birthday.txt', 'a') as f:  # Checking if it already in file or not
            for lines in content:
                if birth_day in content:
                    print(birth_day)
            f.close()

    else:
        print('There is no such name in database')
        print('Do you want to add it on database?')
        choice = input('')
        if choice == 'y':  # if not in file than append upon it
            new_dates = input('What\'t is the birthday of '+name+'?')
            Birthday[name] = new_dates
            new_birthdates = Birthday[name] + 'is a birthday of' + name + '.' + '\n'
            print(new_birthdates)

            with open('Birthday.txt', 'a') as fi:
                fi.write(new_birthdates)
                fi.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are writing to the file try using 'w' instead of a. As a means that you want to append where as you are using the write function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you mind helping one more time.

Comment: I want to avoid data redundancy. If there is same name in file then I want it to be printed so how can I do it?

Comment: Okay so you could use a for loop to go through the file and every time it matches append it to a list then print the list or the item in the list that you need

Comment: How is that done? I am not able to do the same thing.

Comment: Okay for example:                                                                                         a=[] for i in f.readlines(): if i==h:a.append(i). H being the thing you are comparing it to and a being the list

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for your support.

Would you again help me if I don't find the solution??